# SMTP connect() failed phpMailer [out-of-date CA certificate issue]?

Tags: php, email, ssl, phpmailer, fat-free-framework

I've been using phpMailer to send emails **until few days ago**, and it stopped working surprisingly.

I'm using **GMAIL SMTP** server as a host.

Here's what the Exception and debugging message shows in console :

```
2017-12-19 05:39:02 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465, t=10, opt=array (
                                      )
2017-12-19 05:39:02 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server:  (0)
2017-12-19 05:39:02 SMTP connect() failed.
```

And here's my mail functionality:

```
public static function mailTo($recipients)
{
    $f3 = \Base::instance();
    $edit = $f3->get('editTrue');
    $user = AclHelper::getCurrentUser();
    $template= new \Template;
    if(isset($edit))
    {
        $mailBody = $template->render('leave/requestEdit.html');
    }
    else
    {
        $mailBody= $template->render('leave/emailTemp.html');
    }

    // When true, PHPMailer returns exceptions
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    try {
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->isHTML(true);

        $mail->addAddress($user['email']);
        $mail->addAddress("malakar.rakesh1993@gmail.com");

        // foreach($recipients as $recipient){
        //     $mail->addCC($recipient);
        // }
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
        $mail->Username = "malakar.rakesh1993@gmail.com";
        $mail->Password = "abc123";

        // $mail->Host = $f3->get('GBD.smtp.host');   // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->setFrom($user['email']);

        $userFullName = trim(ucfirst($user['firstname'])) . " " . trim(ucfirst($user['lastname']));
        $mail->FromName = $userFullName;
        $mail->Body =  $f3->get('message');
        $mail->Body .="<br>". $mailBody;

        if(isset($edit))
        {
            $mail->AltBody = '';
        }
        else
        {
            $mail->AltBody = 'Hello.. Not working';
        }

        $mail->Subject = 'Updates on leave date applied';

        $mailStatus = (boolean)$mail->send();

        if ($mailStatus === true) 
        {
            return $mail;
        }
    } 
    catch (phpmailerException $e) 
    {
        $response = array(
            'status'=>'error',
            'message'=>'Got some error while sending emails',
            'exceptions'=>$e->getMessage()
        );
        return $response;

    } 
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $response = array(
            'status'=>'error',
            'message'=>'Got some error while sending emails',
            'exceptions'=>$e->getMessage()
        );

        return $response;
    }
}
```

I also tried using **tls** as encryption protocol and **587** port, but gives `500 internal server error`.

The same code is **running** in development version in server, but unfortunately not in my **localhost**.

I was suggested of **out-dated** **CA certificate** in my system, and I tried renewing the up-to-date CA certificate following the link [Trobuleshooting](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting), but it's not working either.

Stupid maybe but I tried pinging to smtp.gmail.com [without ssl and port] in my command prompt and I'm receiving feedback.

Could it be that Google limits email sending? But I can still access my account.

I have followed almost every articles and solutions available in the Internet.

Please help me through this...this is driving me crazy.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: Do you try to re-sync system datetime in OS using ntp.

Comment: @Aggarat.J I don't know what that means.. Can you explain it to me, please??

Comment: Unverifiable certificates won't stop it *trying* to connect (i.e. you're not blocked by a firewall, so ping/telnet will work fine). The troubleshooting guide tells you how to use `openssl` to check certificates on an encrypted connection. If you tell it to use the same CA certs file you're using with PHP, you will replicate PHP's own verification and you'll be able to find which cert is missing or outdated. To be clear, this isn't a PHPMailer problem, it's merely where the symptom shows up in a broken/outdated PHP config.

Comment: @Synchro so you're suggesting that CA cert file is outdated, right?

Comment: Indeed, telnet to port 465 will connect but produce no output, because it's expecting you to talk SSL at it. This is mentioned in the guide. You need to check your certs with `openssl` commands and verify the certificates, like I said.

Comment: @Synchro I get "20(unable to get local issuer certificate)" instead of 0 (OK) on telnet-ing smtp.gmail.com:465... Doc. states "...verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate is not a problem." What does this mean?

Comment: It means you need to read the guide. I’m not about to say anything different to what is in there.

Comment: @Synchro.. thanks... but I'm confused with what the guide has to say.. "not a problem" means do I have to worry about that??

Comment: @Azima I mean that  you have to check your System Date Time on you OS system  , you said that it worked a few days ago , there must be something wrong with your OS datetime rather than PHPmailer or Google SMTP.